# What is the meaning of "&" followed by "|" in shell script

Tags: shell

" |& grep not"
What is the meaning of "&" followed by | in the command and also "grep not"

Comment: [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70963/difference-between-2-2-dev-null-dev-null-and-dev-null-21) might help out some.

Comment: @SrB : Since you expressed interest in Posix compatibility: `|&` doesn't seem to be legal in Posix shells, at least not according to [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07) document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sub>If `|&` is used, **command1’s** *standard error*, in addition to
>   its *standard output*, is connected to **command2’s** *standard input*
>   through the pipe; it is shorthand for `2>&1 |`. This implicit
>   redirection of the standard error to the standard output is performed
>   after any redirections specified by the command.</sub>

↳ [3.2.2 Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) ([`Bash Reference Manual`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/))